# Randomize Time Portion of Date Field

Tags: sql, oracle, random

What is the best way to randomize the time part for a DATE column, using Oracle 10g?

For example, the date portion for the data was set as follows:

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_ts = SYSDATE - 120 + MOD(ROWNUM, 35)
```

I would like the time portion to have a different value for each row.

Comment: Set it equal to 4.  Guaranteed to be random.

Comment: Thanks, Matthew. http://tinyurl.com/3aav3f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose a random number between 0 and 86400 (number of seconds in a day)

Add random / 86400 to your date.

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE)+DBMS_RANDOM.value(0, 86400-1)/86400 FROM DUAL
```

ADDITION:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET    column_ts = SYSDATE - 120 + MOD(ROWNUM, 35) + DBMS_RANDOM.value(0, 86400-1)/86400;
```

Comment: UPDATE table_name
SET    column_ts = SYSDATE - 120 + MOD(ROWNUM, 35) + DBMS_RANDOM.value(0, 86400-1)/86400;

Answer (score 2):

```
select trunc(sysdate)+dbms_random.value from dual;
```

Comment: If DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE returns more than 86400, this will potentially increase the day.  This is probably unwanted.

Comment: DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE is defined to return a number between 0 and 1

Comment: (if you don't pass in any arguments)